# laravel one to one and one to many eloquent relationship best practice

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relational-database

Imagin below requirements:

The soccer teams have three type of users: an owner, mentors and soccer players.

Each soccer player belongs to one of the mentors teams, while mentors on the other hand
can mentor more than one team.

I detect that there is an one to one relationship between teams and soccer players
and on to many relationship between mentors and teams
which defined in User model as below:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Teams::class);
    }


    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Teams::class, 'mentor_id');
    }
}
```

and in Teams model

```
class Teams extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'team_id'); // where team_id is a nullable column in users table for who has soccer player role
   }


   public function mentors()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

I'm looking for best solution to make models and eloquent relationships

Comment: The relation between team and players is one to many (a team has many players) and the relation between team and mentor is One to many too, (a team has only one mentor)

Comment: @N69S you mean make a table for both of them and detect user type with role!?

Comment: I meant exactly as @Jiglant answered.

Answer (score 3):

For what I have seen your question, I can do as follows.

Teams Table

```
| id  | mentor_id | owner_id |
|---- |-----------| ---------|
```

Users table

```
| id  | team_id |
|---- |---------|

team_id can be null for mentor and owner
```

Team Modal

```
class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


   public function players()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(User::class); // where team_id is not null in users table for players
   }


   public function mentor()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'mentor_id'); //team mentor
   }

   public function owner()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'owner_id'); //team owner
   }
}
```

User Modal

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;


   public function ownedTeams()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Team::class,'owner_id'); // teams the user owns if owner
   }


   public function mentoredTeams()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Team::class,'mentor_id'); //teams the user mentors if mentor
   }

   public function team()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Team::class); //team the user plays for if soccer player
   }
}
```

Hope it helps